# How to alter a db column attribute to `NULL` from `NOT-NULL` state using SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write a SQL script that alters a column's attribute to null from the not-null state.

Tried:

```
SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY('prefetching_rules', 'date_delete','AllowsNull') AS 'AllowsNull';
```

But getting following error:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'COLUMNPROPERTY' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

For this you should use  `alter table`  (assuming you column is a varchar of 255)  just apply `modify`.

Columns are nullable by default and so just not assign other constrains as NOT NULL

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY your_column_name VARCHAR(255);
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you detailed info about all 'not nullable' columns 
in all tables in 'your_database_name_here'.

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name_here'
AND IS_NULLABLE = 'NO';
```

Then you have to decide which of them you want to modify.

Just FYI u can't use this query as sub query in ALTER sql because it doesn't accept subqueries